# Create class from meta-data sent by API in Angular 6

Tags: angular, api, typescript, class

I'm currently working on an angular project. I will have to manipulate some objects for this project, but i'll get the proprieties of this class with a call to an API.

The API will give me meta-datas in  JSON, and, as the meta-data will change i can't define a permanent class to manipulate objects.

I did a lot of research but found nothing about that, maybe i did bad research, sorry for my english but thank you by advance for your help!

---

Here is the meta-data i would like to use to create a class

```
const PARTNERSHIP = {
  version: '0.1',
  properties: [
    {
      id: 'id', label: 'ID', description: 'ID description', type: 'S', required: true, readonly: true,
    },
    {
      id: 'label', label: 'Name', description: 'Name description', type: 'S', required: true,
    },
    {
      id: 'description', label: 'Description', description: 'Description description', type: 'S', required: true,
    },
    {
      id: 'active', label: 'Active', description: 'Active', type: 'B', values: [true, false], default: false,
    },
    {
      // * When type == 'E' (enum), look below for description
      id: 'config', label: 'config', description: 'Config', type: 'E', typeRef: 'conf',
    },
    {
      id: 'createdAt', label: 'Created At', description: 'Moment of creation, timestamp in millis, value to be displayed as date', type: 'N', readonly: true,
    },
    {
      id: 'updatedAt', label: 'Updated At', description: 'Moment of update, timestamp in millis, value to be displayed as date', type: 'N', readonly: true,
    },
  ],
```

Comment: what class do you want to create

Comment: What are you after exactly? You don't need a TS class to use angular, you can use the objects returned by the API directly. Then it's up to you to use your metadata correctly to know which fields to display/how to display them

Comment: const PARTNERSHIP = {
  version: '0.1',
  properties: [
    {
      id: 'id', label: 'ID', description: 'ID description', type: 'S', required: true, readonly: true,
    },
    {
      id: 'label', label: 'Name', description: 'Name description', type: 'S', required: true,
    },
    {
      id: 'description', label: 'Description', description: 'Description description', type: 'S', required: true....

For example the API will give me this meta data, so i would like to create a PARTNERSHIP class to manipulate this type of object later. As the meta will change with the version

Comment: Why would you need a class to manipulate objects? Just do `const parsed = JSON.parse(PARTNERSHIP) ` and do with it whatever you'd like.

Comment: Ok, thank you a lot, i was on the wrong way from the beginning maybe due to the angular tutorial where they create class heroes and others. Thank you again!